# Not able to upload file using Laravel backend from Python script

Tags: python, php, laravel, api

I was trying to upload the file from python script to Laravel backend but it's not getting uploaded to server, event getting the empty array in `$request->all()` and false in `$request->has('file)`.

Here's the code that I am using.

1. api.php

```php
Route::post('upload-file', UploadFilesController::class);
```

2. UploadFilesController

```php
class UploadFilesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        return response()->json($request->all()); // getting empty error, also used the $request->hasFile('file') and getting false
    }
}
```

3. Python script

```py
import requests

# Set the API endpoint URL
url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/upload-file"

# Set the file to be uploaded
file_path = "/path/to/file.pdf"

# Set the content type to "multipart/form-data"
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

# Read the file and create the form data
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    file_data = {'file': f}
    # Send the POST request to the API endpoint
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=file_data)

# Print the response from the server
print(response.text)
```

I also used the `headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}` in place of header and it's also not working.

P.S the same code is working in Insomnia REST

Answer (score 0):

1. Use headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
2. Try to log request inside laravel itself or use laravel debugger link https://sentry.io/for/laravel/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=9779875598&utm_content=g&utm_term=%2Blaravel%20%2Bdebugger&device=m&gclid=CjwKCAiAy_CcBhBeEiwAcoMRHI8g4U4aAptz6YRYwRS7g3fYM8-_AdCE63-YAtSc3QHS9XdEamewuxoCPLQQAvD_BwE&gclid=CjwKCAiAy_CcBhBeEiwAcoMRHI8g4U4aAptz6YRYwRS7g3fYM8-_AdCE63-YAtSc3QHS9XdEamewuxoCPLQQAvD_BwE

Comment: I've already try this one, and logs are empty if I am trying this with python but getting logs if I am trying this one with Insomnia REST